# Passing a derived class into a map c++

Tags: c++

What I would like to do is place a manager into a map, and then call functions correlating to each manager. Because I have different types of managers I created a base class like so:

```
class iGyroManager {
public:
    iGyroManager() {}
    virtual ~iGyroManager() = default;

    virtual bool preInit() = 0;

    virtual bool init() = 0;

    virtual bool postInit() = 0;

    virtual void update() = 0;

    virtual void cleanup() = 0;
}
```

Pretty straight forward and obviously works like a charm.

Then I do the following to create a derived class:

```
class GyroAudioManager : public iGyroManager {
public:
    GyroAudioManager();
    ~GyroAudioManager() override;

    bool preInit() override;

    bool init() override;

    bool postInit override;

    void update() override;

    bool cleanup() override;
}
```

Again, simple and straight forward. The cpp is very basic and just declares the bare functions.

I then create one final derived class:

```
class GyroAppStateManager : iGyroManager {
private:
    std::map<int, iGyroManager&> m_managerMap;

public:
    GyroAppStateManager();
    ~GyroAppStateManager() override;

    bool preInit() override;

    bool init() override;

    bool postInit() override;

    int start();

    void update() override;

    bool registerManager(iGyroManager& manager);

    bool cleanup() override;
}
```

That seems to work, but it's in the registerManager function where it falls apart:

```
bool GyroAppStateManager::registerManager(iGyroManager& manager) {
    // Try to insert a derived class into a base class map using what
    // should be working.
    m_managerMap.insert(1, manager);

    return true;
}
```

And in the calling function:

```
int start() {
    GyroAudioManager m_audioManager = GyroAudioManager();

    mp_appStateManager->registerManager(m_audioManager);


    /* use mp_appStateManager here, while m_audioManager is alive */
}
```

Except this does not seem to work at all and spits out the following:

```
error: no matching function for call to std::map<int, iGyroManager&>::insert(int, iGyroManager&)
```

So my question is what am I doing wrong? As I mentioned above, I'd like to add multiple different manager classes that derive a single base class to this map and then be able to run certain functions from it.

Is there actually a way of doing it?

Comment: `class GyroAppStateManager : iGyroManager` is private inheritance, which means only the class itself can upcast (or do anything else providing access to the base subobject).

You probably meant
`class GyroAppStateManager : public iGyroManager`

Comment: Then, your `start()` function makes a reference to a local variable that's short-lived.  Storing such a reference is not wise.

Comment: Why not use `std::map<int, shared_ptr<iGyroManager>>` ?

Comment: This is a very limited sample, but nothing in it suggests multiple owners. I'd start with `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: The only incorrect part in your code is the [`insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/) call. Change its parameters to match the signature  - either `insert(std::pair<int, iGyroManager>(1, manager))` or `insert(m_managerMap.begin(), std::pair<int, iGyroManager>(1, manager))`.

Comment: @fzd: You're correct the only problem is `insert`, but both your suggested fixes are extremely bad, because they'll copy the object into a temporary `pair`.  There are two big problems with this: slicing and lifetime.

Comment: That was a typo on my part iGyroManager is in fact public. Also, starts local variable is actually declared in the header and defined in start

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You can't have a standard container of references.  I'm still looking for the exact wording of the restriction, but in the meantime</strike> you might want to try `std::reference_wrapper` instead, or a container of (smart) pointers, which also allows polymorphism.

Actually, `value_type` is `std::pair<key_type, mapped_type>` which is an object type even when `mapped_type` is a reference.  So that's ok.

The error is caused because the parameter to `std::map<Key,Value>::insert` is a `pair<Key,Value>`, not two separate arguments.  Try

```
m_managerMap.insert({1, manager});
```

But then you need to arrange to reference an object that isn't destroyed immediately afterward, when `start()` returns.

Comment: start() should not return until the end of program life. I wrote it as the start point of the program and outright returns to mains return.

Comment: @JamieEdwards: Ahh, that should be ok.  I'll make a small edit to your question so no one else gets tripped up by that.